# Is an adjacent lightest edge in an MST

Tags: algorithm, graph, minimum-spanning-tree

In an undirected and connected graph, if e is the lightest edge adjacent to a vertex v, then is e part of some MST?

I said yes because an MST has all the lightest edges chosen, is this correct thinking?

Answer (score 1):

Let T be a minimum weight spanning tree and vw be a lightest edge incident to v. Let P be the unique path in T between v and w. If P is not vw itself, then it contains some other edge vx. Let T' be the set of edges derived from T by inserting vw and removing vx. I claim (1) T' is at least as light as T, since vw is at least as light as vx (2) T' is a tree, since it connects everything (for each walk in T, derive a related walk in T' with the same endpoints by replacing vx with vw and the rest of P) and has the right number of edges, hence (3) T' is a minimum weight spanning tree that contains vw.

Comment: nice. +1. page 14 is also proposed the same things isnt it?

https://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~yvchen/f106-ada/doc/171130_Graph2.pdf

Comment: @DaviedZuhraph yep. This is known as the basis exchange property.

Comment: Thanks a lot. one last question would you please see page 33, 34 and 35 on the following link !! these are cut property and cut rule and cycle property and cycle rule, why use two different words property and rule? https://www.cs.upc.edu/~mjserna/docencia/grauA/T16/Greedyfib.pdf

Comment: is there any idea ?